# Check CMTime Equals

Tags: objective-c, time, compare, equals, cmtime

Is there any method to check a CMTime is equal to another CMTime. In my case I need to check CMTime is equal to KCMTimeZero. I tried CMTimeCompare method, but it will be True for all the CMTimes which is equal to KCMTimeZero or greater than KCMTimeZero.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the following way to check by converting it to seconds

```
if(CMTimeGetSeconds(myTime) == CMTimeGetSeconds(kCMTimeZero))
{
     // do something...     
}
```

Comment: VishnuKumar : Thank you                 .

Comment: @VineeshTP: Welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

`CMTimeCompare` does that trick,

from `Xcode`'s documentation `CMTimeReference`:

```
int32_t CMTimeCompare ( CMTime time1, CMTime time2 );
```

Return Value
*The numerical relationship of the two CMTimes.*

- -1 is returned if time1 is less than time2.
- 1 is returned if time1 is greater than time2.
- 0 is returned if time1 and time2 are equal.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer using `CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE` macro defined in `CMTime.h` to keep code more readable. 
Here is the code for your case (comparison with kCMTimeZero):

```
if (CMTIME_COMPARE_INLINE(myTime, ==, kCMTimeZero))
{
    // Your code here
}
```